# SpEL: Projection of list elements to map

Tags: java, spring-el

I hava a Spring Data MongoDB managed entity which stores a list of elements within their subcollection. In order to return only a subset of this entity via Spring MVC I am using [projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.9.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections) to customize the view on the data object.

A simplified sample to visualize my setup:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "test")
public class CompanyEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private List<Employee> employees;
    ...
}
```

with User being:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

The view is a simple interface looking like this:

```
public interface CompanyView {

    String getId();
    @Value("#{target.employees.![name]}")
    List<String> getEmployeeNames();
}
```

While I'm able to project the employee's name directly to a list via `#{target.employees.![name]}` directly, I'm somehow lost on trying to replace the current code with a map using the `employee.id` as key and the `employee.name` as value.

Is this even possible or do I have to write a [custom function](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-functions) therefore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I've found a solution I'm satisfied with.

In order to create something like:

```
@Value("#{target...}")
Map<String, String> getEmployees();
```

I'm now defining a new sub projection called `EmployeeView` which I use as type for the `List` to return.

```
public interface EmployeeView {
    String getId();
    String getName();
}
```

In the `CompanyView` the definition does look like this now:

```
@Value("#{target.employees}")
List<EmployeeView> getEmployees();
```

This returns only the limited subset of the employees within the returned data.